# AWS Equivalent For Incremental SQL Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, incremental-build

I can create a materialised view in RDS (postgreSQL) to keep track of the 'latest' data output from a SQL query, and then visualise this in QuickSight. This process is also very 'quick' as it doesn't result in calling additional AWS services and/or re-processing all data again (through the SQL query). My assumption is how this works is it runs a SQL, re-runs the SQL but not for the whole data again, so that if you structure the query correctly, you can end up having a 'real time running total' metric for example.

The issue is, creating materialised views (per 5 seconds) for 100's of queries, and having them all stored in a database is not scalable. Imagine a DB with 1TB data, creating an incremental/materialised view seems much less painful than using other AWS services, but eventually won't be optimal for processing time/cost etc.

I have explored various AWS services, none of which seem to solve this problem.

1. I tried using AWS Glue. You would need to create 1 script per query and output it to a DB. The lag between reading and writing the incremental data is larger than creating a materialised view; because you can incrementally process data, but then to append it to the current 'total' metric is another process.
2. I explored using AWS Kinesis followed by a Lambda to run a SQL on the 'new' data in the stream, and store the value in S3 or RDS. Again, this adds latency and doesn't work as well as a materialised view.
3. I read that AWS Redshift does not have materialised views therefore stuck to RDS (PostgreSQL).

Any thoughts?

[A similar issue: [incremental SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057092/incremental-sql-query) - except I want to avoid running the SQL on "all" data to avoid massive processing costs.]

Edit (example):

- table1 has schema (datetime, customer_id, revenue)
- I run this query: select sum(revenue) from table1.
- This would scan the whole table to come up with a metric per customer_id.
- table1 now gets updated with new data as the datetime progresses e.g. 1 hour extra data.
- If I run select sum(revenue) from table1 again, it scans all the data again.
- A more efficient way is to just compute the query on the new data, and append the result.
- Also, I want the query to actively run where there is a change in data, not have to 'run it with a schedule' so that my front end dashboards basically 'auto update' without the customer doing much.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this `I can create a materialised view in RDS (postgreSQL) to keep track of the 'latest' data output from a SQL query`. How do materialised views help with incremental data? Are you creating a new view every time the data changes? I think some sort of trigger based summary is going to be a better solution. Need to understand more about the use case though.

Comment: @TomC - I added an example above to help.

Comment: You basically want streaming. How does the data get into your database? Stream it instead using Kafka or something like that.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - its the SQL query I'm trying to automate pro-actively, not necessarily the streaming part. I can use Kafka sure, that would flow the data in real time, but the SQL would have to be repeatedly executed.

Comment: This sounds like a classic trigger use-case to me.

Comment: If you were to use Kafka you would even put it in SQL you'd stream it from the source (whatever that may be). If you're looking non-interactive real time, pushing the data into an enormous table then pulling it out again is redundant. Don't get stuck on materialised views. Redshift may not have them but it does have MPP and columnar storage which might simply perform better.

Comment: Another approach is to use a 'cube' layer that allows incremental updates. cube's are fast for analytics, and you can just refresh a recent partition in it. For analytics. you're always going to run out of steam in a relational database unless you look into MPP (Redshift, Azure Synapse)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - I was thinking to use Kinesis/Kinesis Analytics but you would need 1 SQL query per pipeline. This would mean you end up having multiple pipelines just for one dashboard. Agreed on Redshift but you need to manually execute a query. Cube is available in AWS?